# Skip confirmation in Ansible during deleting node with Kubspray

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci, kubespray

I'm trying to run  Ansible playbook remove-node.yml from Kubespray repository.
But when I run a job I get an error:

```
TASK [check confirmation] ******************************************************
fatal: [node61]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Delete nodes confirmation failed"}
```

I'm doing it through GitLabCI and here is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - deploy

image: ***/releases/kubespray:v2.12.5

variables:
  ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: "False"

before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$id_rsa" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh

delete_node:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - ansible-playbook -v -u root --key-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa --extra-vars skip_confirmation=yes -i inventory/hosts.ini /kubespray/remove-node.yml -e "node=node61"
```

I've tried check_confirmation, skip_confirmation=true, True or 'true' and other variations, but none of them works

Answer (score 1):

The required variable is `delete_nodes_confirmation` not `skip_confirmation`.
So the answer is `delete_nodes_confirmation=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your script like this?

```
ansible-playbook -v -u root --key-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa -i inventory/hosts.ini /kubespray/remove-node.yml --extra-var "node=node61 skip_confirmation=true"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).